# Odoo filtered one2many

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I have a model with `one2many` field `mes_indicator_sub_group_ids`.I tried this but nothing is filtered even that I know there is a record with id 5:

```
  http.request.env['table.test'].sudo().search([('id', '=', int(category))]).filtered(lambda x: x.mes_indicator_sub_group_ids.ids in [5])
```

what I need is to filter record of `table.test` that have only one record in `mes_indicator_sub_group_ids` and its `ID == 5.`

**EDITS**

I have a model `model.mes_indicator_group`, which contains two one2many fields, `mes_indicator_sub_group_ids` and `mes_indicator_ids`. I want to get recordset which relates to `model.mes_indicator_group` with id=1 and `mes_indicator_sub_group_ids` with id=5. For example I want to get mes_indicator_ids from `first` group and `fifth` subgroup. Just get data, not unlink or write. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: can you put your code, what do you mean by get and what will you do with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter record that have only one record in the one2many field and it's Id should be 5, just make sure the length is one and the id of record is 5:

```py
http.request.env['table.test'].sudo().search(your_domain).filtered(lambda x: len(x.mes_indicator_sub_group_ids) == 1 and x.mes_indicator_sub_group_ids.id  == 5)
```

don't worry about `x.mes_indicator_sub_group_ids.id` it will not cause a problem because it contains only one record.

The problem here you are using `search([('id', '=', int(category))])` with this type of domain you will always have only one record, it will be nicer if you write an `if statement` that explain what you are doing for your team, and when you deal with `ID` use browse it's more clear:

```py
   rec = http.request.env['table.test'].sudo().browse(int(category))
   if len(rec.mes_indicator_sub_group_ids) == 1 and rec.mes_indicator_sub_group_ids.id  == 5):
         # do what you need to do with this record
```

**EDITS**

Here you have two solution if you want to delete them completly from database or you 
just want to remove them from one2many it's up to you.

```py
    rec = http.request.env['table.test'].sudo().browse(int(category))
    # this remove all record from database keeps only record with 5
    rec.mes_indicator_sub_group_ids.filtered(lambda x : x.id != 5).unlink()  

    # this will remove the record from the one2many but keeps them in teh database
    rec.mes_indicator_sub_group_ids = [(6,0, [5])]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But if I add `.mapped('mes_indicator_sub_group_ids')` after all of your's three examples and print it it's return recordset of all `mes_indicator_sub_group_ids` not just with id=5.

Comment: Sorry i was confused I thought you want to filter records of table.test but now I see that you only have one record so you need to filter indecator record. I notice that you used id this means that you have only one record you don't have to use mapped at all just filter the record of the one2many direclty. checkout my edits and I added another solution by searching directly in the indecator model.

Comment: thanks again. Sorry for misleading you. But I really want  to filter records of table.test. And then call another method(which exist in table.test) on this object(table.test which contains only `mes_indicator_sub_group_ids.ids =5`). Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: confusing first I thought that you to filter record of table.test that at least one if it's indecator have an id 5. do you want this or you want to filter record of table.test that contains only one record in one2many with id 5? or you want something else

Comment: I want to filter record of table.test that contains only one record in one2many with id 5

Comment: Sorry that waste your time. Forexample, I have record `http.request.env['table.test'].sudo().browse(int(category))` wich contains many different`mes_indicator_sub_group_ids` and I want to filter this exactly this record(`http.request.env['table.test'].sudo().browse(int(category))`) that after filtering it's contains only 1 mes_indicator_sub_group_ids with id 5.

Comment: If I understand you want to remove other records from it, you want to keep only one record in the one2many field.

Comment: if it was in sql it's looks like `SELECT *
FROM labs_mes_indicator_group AS mi_group
INNER JOIN labs_mes_indicator_sub_group AS mi_sub ON mi_group.id = mi_sub.mes_indicator_group_id
WHERE mi_group.id = 62
AND mi_sub.id IN (5)`

Comment: and what do you want to do with this record, and what about other record `id != 5`, can you edit your question and put the hole code to understand what you want to do exaclty.

Comment: Edit my question. Sorry again